# How do I split imported XML points into separate groups?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, geometry, point

I'm trying to import an XML file that contains a list of points for a drawLine function, it's the typical drawLine function, give it your X1, Y1, X2, Y2 coordinates and it will draw the line. What I have in my XML file is as follows:

```
<LINES>
  <LINE>
    <ID>J3U93</ID>
    <POINT X="454.5" Y="93.5"></POINT>
    <POINT X="454.5" Y="371"></POINT>
    <POINT X="433.5" Y="351"></POINT>
    <POINT X="433.5" Y="329.5"></POINT>
  </LINE>
  <LINE>
    <ID>U231U93</ID>
    <POINT X="23.5" Y="526"></POINT>
    <POINT X="417" Y="341.875"></POINT>
    <POINT X="380" Y="341.875"></POINT>
    <POINT X="188.5" Y="526"></POINT>
    <POINT X="23.5" Y="526"></POINT>
  </LINE>
   .
   .
</LINES>
```

Each line has an ID to distinguish it in the file, my lines will join up up to essentially form Z shape patterns i.e. varied amount of turns depending on the amount of points are within the LINE tag.

What I need would like to know, or if you can point me in the right direction is how do I separate one set of lines within the ID tags from another set of lines in another ID tag?

So far I tried:

```
List<Point> Points;

XDocument lineDataXml = XDocument.Load(filename);

Points = (
     from point in lineDataXml.Descendants("LINE")
      select new Point 
      { 
          X = Double.Parse(point.Attribute("X").Value), 
          Y = Double.Parse(point.Attribute("Y").Value) 
      }).ToList();

 foreach(Point a in Points)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(a);
 }
```

but this returns a list of all points in the XML without knowing what points belong to which ID.

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Peter.

Comment: Can you show us an example of two lines? I don't understand the structure of your data.

Comment: iterate each Line, group them by ID, then select a new object that contains the ID, StartPoint and EndPoint.

Comment: Also, all I see in your code is a Point object, to represent a point. Do you have a Line object with which to group your points?

Comment: Hi Cyborgx37, 
here is a screenshot of what the lines will look like: [here](http://peterfleming.net84.net/lines.png).
Also, yes there is a line object further in the code, i pass the drawline function the start point and end point of the line, it returns a line object, which is stored in an array. my situation is that all these lines are hard coded into the program where i want them to be in the XML file as a resource instead.

Comment: @Peter - I meant two lines within your XML document. You only have one line.

Comment: Apologies, i re-edited the question and added another set of line data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
var lines = root.Descendants("LINE")
    .Select(line =>
        new
        {
            Id = (string)line.Element("ID"),
            Points = line.Elements("POINT")
                .Select(p => new PointF
                {
                    X = (float)p.Attribute("X"),
                    Y = (float)p.Attribute("Y")
                }).ToArray()
        }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck, i will try this and see how it goes for me.

Comment: You can replace line => new {...} with line => new Line() {...}